# Getting and setting style not working?

Tags: javascript

I have some code like this:

```
var content = document.getElementById('myDivId');

function MyFunction()
{
     alert(content.style.height);
}
```

For some reason, I'm not getting any message box.  I have the "body onload" equal to "MyFunction()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have

```
var content = document.getElementById('myDivId');
```

just free-floating in your script, because then it will run before the `myDivId` element has actually been created, so `content` won't end up referring to it. Try putting it inside your onload-handler:

```
function MyFunction()
{
      var content = document.getElementById('myDivId');
      alert(content.style.height);
}
```

instead; or, if you want it to be globally visible, you can at least initialize it inside your onload-handler:

```
var content; // declare globally

function MyFunction()
{
      content = document.getElementById('myDivId'); // initialize
      alert(content.style.height);
}
```